# Why is Bootstrap modal closed slowly when triggered by data-dismiss="modal"

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I tried a simple modal as a dialog box with a "#cancel" button that closes the modal.
Any idea why the modal goes away much slower when i apply data-dismiss="modal" to "#cancel"

```
<button id="cancel" type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-boglow" data-      
dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
```

compared to manually trigger it:

```
$('body .modal-footer #cancel').on("click", function() {
  $(this).closest(".modal").modal("hide");
  return false;
});
```

My guess is there might be animation involved but i'm not sure how to disable that. Below is the whole modal in html:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="glossary-modal" data-backdrop="static" tabindex="-1"        role="dialog" aria-labelledby="glossary-term" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h3 class="modal-title" id="glossary-term">ghost term</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <input id="glossary-definition" type="text" autofocus="autofocus" placeholder="Define this term" autocomplete="off">
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button id="cancel" type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-boglow" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
      <button id="save" type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-ngglow">Save</button>
      <button id="glossary-link" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-dbglow">View glossary</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you used "modal" instead of "modal-fade", so it slowly fades away. The solution is to use "modal". It will go away directly.

```
<div class="modal"></div> instead of <div class="modal fade"></div>
```

Comment: I tried that, now my modal begins with: <div class="modal" id="glossary-modal" data-backdrop="static" tabindex="-1"        role="dialog" aria-labelledby="glossary-term" aria-hidden="true">, but it doesn't improve, still much slower than the manual trigger

Comment: Did that too actually, still slow

Comment: i have implement the same code, and the modal get dismiss in less than a second , May be issue with ur configuration or data consumption